# Remove border from Material UI Modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, simplemodal

I am trying to use the React Material UI `Modal` but I always get a black border around the modal when it is focused on. I have removed the border when it is out of focus, but if the modal is focused, the border comes back. Any suggestions on how to remove it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kk0ux?file=/demo.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3)
  },
  modal: {
    "&:focus": {
      outline: "none"
    }
  }
}));

export default function SimpleModal() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  // getModalStyle is not a pure function, we roll the style only on the first render
  const [modalStyle] = React.useState(getModalStyle);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const body = (
    <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
      <h2 id="simple-modal-title">Text in a modal</h2>
      <p id="simple-modal-description">
        Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
      </p>
      <SimpleModal />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open Modal
      </button>
      <Modal
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you used google? [Result 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675116/how-i-can-remove-the-blue-border-in-material-react-modal) [Result 2](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11504) [Result 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996690/how-to-remove-focused-highlight-in-react-material-ui-tab-component) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove focused highlight in React material-ui Tab Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996690/how-to-remove-focused-highlight-in-react-material-ui-tab-component)

Comment: Make sure you explicitly need to remove it; this comes up frequently during accessibility reviews.

Comment: @0stone0 yes I have googled and tried those results but nothing seemed to work. setting focus, hover, or active outline to none did not fix it. Adding disableAutoFocus also did not fix it.

Answer (score 32):

Set the `outline: 'none'` to your paper instead. That will fix your problem.

Also, i think that you should be using `<Dialog>` instead, as recommended in [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/#modal). You will keep your behavior without that focus.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I needed to apply the styling on paper. Will look into Dialog. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the body of the Modal tag in a  and provide outline: none as a style

```
<div style={{outline:'none'}}>     
    {body}    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your makeStyles

```
modal:{
    "&:focus":{
    outline: 'none"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Modal` is a low level component to create a [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/) which should be preferred in most cases instead. The `Modal` container itself doesn't have a border by default, in case you copy the code from the first example [here](https://mui.com/components/modal/#basic-modal), you may want to remove the `border` and `boxShadow` properties if you don't want it:

```
const style = {
  position: 'absolute' as 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  // comment the 2 lines below
  // border: '2px solid #000',
  // boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

```
const style = {
   position: 'absolute',
   top: '50%',
   left: '50%',
   transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
   // width: 400,
   bgcolor: 'background.paper',
   boxShadow: 24,
   borderRadius: '20px',
   background: '#FFF',
   outline: 'none', // add this in your code 
};

<Modal
    open={modalStatus}
    onClose={modalHandleClose}
    aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
  >
   /* add style here in the box */
    <Box sx={style}>Hello</Box>
  </Modal>
```